# Import Multiple Text Files from Multiple Folders in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I need to do some text miner tasks using R. My text files is distributed in several folder, which constitutes it's classes.

So I need to create a "corpus" which constitutes a data file with two columns: Class | Text.

Important to note that the texts can't be edited, just read as it is. The following R code do some of the job, but doesn't attribute the folder name as the text class.

```
text.files  <- list.files(path="/home/ricardo/MultiClass/data/", recursive=T, pattern="*.txt", full.names=T) 
readDatFile <- function(f) {dat.fl <- read.table(f, header=FALSE)}
text.data <- sapply(text.files, readDatFile)
```

Any help?

Thanks
Ricardo.

Comment: just expand your function to add a new column to the output of `read.table()` with `f` as the value

Comment: Hi Natan, in fact the right code is: text.files  <- list.files(path="/home/ricardo/MultiClass/data/", recursive=T, pattern="*.txt", full.names=T) 
readDatFile <- function(f) {dat.fl <- read.table(f, header=FALSE)}
text.data <- sapply(text.files, readDatFile)
Now I see that the first line in each text.data[ ] is the label I need. Can I apply the same suggestion?

Comment: I was thinking like this function `readDatFile <- function(f) {dat.fl <- read.table(f, header = F); dat.fl$original.file <- f}`  Does that work?

Comment: Gives the following error: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "original.file", value = "/home/ricardo/MultiClass/data//F22/869.txt") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0`

Comment: that looks like the file you are trying to read in is empty, thus you are getting an empty data.frame in `dat.fl` and when we try to append it complains because of this. Is that possible?

Comment: (SOLVED) 
`text.files  <- list.files(path="/home/ricardo/MultiClass/data/", 
                          recursive=T, 
                          pattern="*.txt", 
                          full.names=T)    

readDatFile <- function(f) {
  dat.fl <- readLines(f)
  }
text.data <- sapply(text.files, readDatFile)
cls <- names(text.data)`